# Is defensive copying enough to create immutable thread safe classes from mutable thread unsafe ones?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, immutability

According to what I've read about multithreading, if you want to create an immutable thread safe class consisting of mutable thread unsafe classes, you need to make defensive copies of the mutable objects passed to the constructor so that if some of them change afterwards, you still keep the original version in the created object. Example:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Person {
    private final String name;
    private final Date birthDate;
    ...
    public Person(final String name, final Date birthDate, ...) {
        this.name = name;
        this.birthDate = new Date(birthDate.getTime());
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Isn't it possible for some other thread to modify the birth date passed to the constructor after the constructor is invoked but before the defensive copy is made?

If yes, then doesn't the code calling the constructor need to ensure that the passed birth date is not modified while the constructor executes?

Doesn't that violate one of the definitions of a thread safe class, that one that states that a class is thread safe if it behaves correctly in a multi threaded environment without any additional synchronization on the part of its clients?

Is there any other way to ensure thread safety?

Comment: Why would this not be thread safe? Only one thread will initialize the object.

Comment: You have pointed out one limitation of the "copy object" strategy for ensuring thread safety. It is too broad of an answer to mention all the other solutions to ensure thread safety in this case

Comment: @AndrewJenkins the Date parameter is not immutable

Comment: @ControlAltDel Ah thank you. Java has some bizarre design choices...

Comment: How about passing primitives types like long, int ?

Comment: How about just one solution for this particular case?

Comment: @AndrewJenkins java.util.Date was created over 20 years ago.  I think you’ll find most if not all libraries of that period were designed poorly.  Fortunately, Date, like most of Java’s early mistakes, has a [replacement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in theory, the birthDate passed in could be changed between the call to the Person constructor and the defensive-copy.  This would assume that that birthDate value was not otherwise thread-safe.  Normally, if you were worried about this, you would put a synchronize block around it somehow to insure no such craziness was occurring.  Since that synchronize would extend around the Person constructor as well, you would be well defended.

You would only need to synchronize around the constructor invocation.  Once it was constructed, a defensive copy exists and other Person methods are thread-safe.

Thread safety can be achieved in many ways - defensive copy, synchronization, use of javax.concurrency package or just proper design.  These all have weaknesses that have to be understood.

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't it possible for some other thread to modify the birth date
>   passed to the constructor after the constructor is invoked but before
>   the defensive copy is made?

Yes, its possible.

> If yes, then doesn't the code calling the constructor need to ensure
>   that the passed birth date is not modified while the constructor
>   executes?

Yes, it should if you are calling `Person` constructor from multiple threads i.e. instead of sharing created instance, you are creating instances from various threads. In my opinion, usually, that is rare.

> Doesn't that violate one of the definitions of a thread safe class,
>   that one that states that a class is thread safe if it behaves
>   correctly in a multithreaded environment without any additional
>   synchronization on the part of its clients?

I guess, **NO** since thread-safe class generally means that you can pass on **correctly constructed instance** of a thread-safe class to multiple threads i.e. you will create instances in some kind of **master thread** first then you will use same instance in many **slave/child/dependent threads** to correctly call its business methods. If you are not following this design, you are free to use `synchronization` around `Person` constructor i.e. certainly defensive copying will not be enough.

Thread-safety usually means that any business methods of that class can be called from various threads and it will produce correct behavior and its assumed that object is already constructed which means that you will have to use synchronization in those business methods of `Person` class since it has mutable state.

Defensive copy is simply freeing up `Person` class from a `Date` object created else where outside `Person` class and that is all business methods need to correctly synchronize themselves.

If somebody says to me that his class is thread - safe , it generally means to me as a client that I can call business methods of that class from multiple threads but I wouldn't be creating instances in multiple threads i.e. there wouldn't be a race condition among threads to even create a single shared instance.

Whole point of concurrency is **Single Shared Instance**.

Hope it helps !!